# Identify the absence of a player on the page and send a request for remove

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, dom-events, game-development

I study on JavaScript, create an online game. I have a problem: it is necessary to remove the player from the room (by closing the tab, by closing the browser, by going to another page); I try to use the `beforeunload` and `unload` events, but I can't track it. Share your experience, there may be another way to remove a player from a room?

```
addEventListener('unload', (event) => {
    /**
     * Send notify of your absence in room.
     */
    $.post("/ajax/player/remove", {
        userID: window.user.id,
        roomID: window.room.id
    });
});
```

Comment: try `$.ajax` method

Comment: There is [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) that might be better suited here. The information there might be useful too. Though you can't guarantee that you always get a signal when a user closes their browser. (If there is a sudden power outage, no signal will ever be sent.) If you use websockets you might be able to detect when they are closed. Otherwise you need to time them out after you haven't received a signal for a period of time. (Might be combined with occasionally sending pings to the server.)

Comment: @debugger How can this help?